# How to display a 3D numpy array (angiography - dicom file) frame by frame with PyQt?

Tags: 3d, pyqt, numpy-ndarray, medical-imaging, image-rendering

I am currently started to use PyQt as a GUI. I would like to create a mini application, which can display a 3D numpy array frame by frame, which is actually an angiography Dicom file, it is a time series image sequence.

I searched the internet I have found some similar projects but they did not do the same what I actually want. I am new in this topic so I do not know how to implement the algorithm. I have also found that with QTDesigner it is easy to create my own little GUI, but the difficulty comes when I have to load this 3D array and I have to integrate it with my GUI.

Comment: Share a minimal example code of the issue you are having,
So maybe someone can help.

Comment: Sorry but we don't answer such broad "how to do something" questions. Please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), but remember that we can only answer to questions about specific and detailed problems. If you *did* try to solve your problem, then please share those attempts in form of a [mre], but if you are asking us how to do that from scratch, then sorry but that's not a question that can be asked here. Start by looking for tutorials on *separate* subjects, then try to put all together.